# How does the WHO calculate the interaction of mortality effects from indoor and outdoor air pollution?

Tags: air-pollution

The WHO's [landing page on air pollution](https://www.who.int/health-topics/air-pollution) includes three different estimates of deaths due to air pollution:

- 7 million total
- 4.2 million due to outdoor (ambient) air pollution
- 3.8 due to household (indoor) air pollution

Obviously, `7 < 4.2 + 3.8`, so there must be some way in which they decide some of those deaths were caused by a combination of indoor and outdoor air pollution. **But what is this methodology?**

---

It's unclear where that 7 million figure originates from, so there's a chance it's a case of [citogenesis](https://xkcd.com/978/), and someone just did the math wrong. It appears in WHO's 2021 [global air quality guidelines](https://www.who.int/publications/i/item/9789240034228) (section 1.3.3), which cites [Burden of disease from ambient air pollution for 2016](https://www.who.int/airpollution/data/AAP_BoD_results_May2018_final.pdf?ua=1), where the 7 million figure *does not* appear.

Answer (score 2):

WHO page [Indicator 3.9.1: Mortality rate attributed to household and ambient air pollution (per 100 000 population)](https://www.who.int/data/gho/data/indicators/indicator-details/GHO/ambient-and-household-air-pollution-attributable-death-rate-(per-100-000-population)) has this information in the "metadata" tab:

> **Method of estimation:**
>
> [...]
> To estimate the combined effects of risk factors, a joint population attributable fraction is calculated, as described in Ezzati et al (2003).

[Ezzati et al (2003)](https://doi.org/10.1016/S0140-6736(03)13968-2) defined the joint [population attributable fraction](https://www.who.int/data/gho/indicator-metadata-registry/imr-details/1287) ($PAF$) for $n$ biologically independent and uncorrelated risk factors, as (their equation 2):

$PAF = 1 - \prod_{i=1}^n(1-PAF_i)$

where $PAF_i$ is the population attributable fraction of individual risk factors.

Comment: +1. Nice find. Is there enough information to show the calculation? i.e. how to get to 7 million total from the 4.2 and 3.8 million figures? The Ezzati paper is behind a paywall, and WHO's explanation only includes the formula, not the calculation.

Comment: I've had a look but the data seems to be only by country, I couldn't find global data. So I guess to try to reproduce the calculation, you'd have to calculate each country's contribution to the total by multiplying its mortality rate by its population...